# MQMessage without header

Tags: java, jms, websphere-8

I got an awesome `ConsumerClass` with the `WebsphereMQClasses` put  got one problem. Instead of giving the message it shows the `_Whole_thing  (JMSMessage class: jms_text etc)` so I wonder how I can get the message without the header. I found this:

```
((MQDestination)destination).setMessageBodyStyle
                          (WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ);
```

But it does not work (at all)
Here is my class:

```
package mq.pack;

import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage;
import com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

public class Consumer {
private MQConnection cnct;
private MQSession session;
private MQMessageConsumer cons;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run() throws JMSException, NamingException, Throwable {
    try {

        MQConnectionFactory factory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName("localhost");
        factory.setPort(1414);
        factory.setQueueManager("QM01");
        factory.setChannel("SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");
        factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
        cnct = (MQConnection) factory.createConnection();
        session = (MQSession) cnct.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MQDestination queue =  (MQDestination) session.createQueue("QUEUE1");
        cnct.start();
        cons = (MQMessageConsumer) session.createConsumer(queue);
        JMSTextMessage msg = (JMSTextMessage) cons.receive(1000);


        if (msg instanceof TextMessage){
            System.out.println("Message:"+msg);
        }
        else {
            //String mes= msg.toString();
            System.out.println("No Textmessage");
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public static void main(String[]args) throws JMSException, NamingException, Throwable{

    Consumer send = new Consumer();
    send.run();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
System.out.println("Message:"+msg);
```

to:

```
System.out.println("Message:"+msg.getText());
```

Comment: .. i shouldve  seen that xD hanks for the fast help.